# How to change the color scheme of CDateTimeCtrl in MFC?

Tags: mfc

I need to change the colors of the background, the text, the color of the dropdown button of
`CDateTimeCtrl` in MFC. I created new class derived from `CDateTimeCtrl` and tried overwritten `OnCtlColor` and `CtlColor`, but these functions are never called (the message map has been added using the Class Wizard). How should I achieve this without writing a completely new *datetimectrl* class of my own?

Comment: You must override "OnCtlColor" function in something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60095590/drawing-text-in-a-custom-combobox/60097546#60097546

Comment: It seems that the CDateTimeCtrl control is different from CCombBox. The CDateTimeCtrl does not call OnCtlColor.

Comment: Windows makes it particularly difficult to do your own color themes.  Sometimes you really do need to re-implement the control from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```cpp
// header
CBrush* m_pBkgBrush { nullptr };
COLORREF m_bkgColor { RGB(255, 255, 255) };

COLORREF SetBackgroundColor(BOOL bSysColor, COLORREF cr);
```

and implementation now:

```cpp
CYourDateTimeCtrl::CYourDateTimeCtrl()
    : CDateTimeCtrl()
    , m_bkgColor(::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW))
{
    m_pBkgBrush = new CBrush(::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW));
}

CYourDateTimeCtrl::~CYourDateTimeCtrl()
{
    if (nullptr != m_pBkgBrush)
        delete m_pBkgBrush;
}

COLORREF CYourDateTimeCtrl::SetBackgroundColor(BOOL bSysColor, COLORREF cr)
{
    COLORREF color = m_bkgColor;
    m_bkgColor = bSysColor ? ::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW) : cr;

    if (color != m_bkgColor)
    {
        delete m_pBkgBrush;
        m_pBkgBrush = new CBrush(m_bkgColor);
            Invalidate();
    }

    return color;
}

BOOL CYourDateTimeCtrl::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC) 
{
    CBrush* pOldBrush = pDC->SelectObject(m_pBkgBrush);
    CRect rect;
    pDC->GetClipBox(&rect);
    pDC->PatBlt(rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), PATCOPY);
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldBrush);
    return TRUE;
}
```

When you use, you do:

```cpp
MyMonthCalCtrl.SetBackgroundColor(FALSE, RGB(255, 255, 0));
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I will give it a try. What about the text color and the colors of the dropdown button on the right side?